# How do you know when to use kinematic equations as apposed to $v = d/t$ and $a = v/t$?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

How do I know when to use v = d/t and a = v/t or d=vi+​1/2​​at^2 and vf = vi + at?​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If acceleration is linear, use the 'kinematic equations'.  If not, use differentiation/integration (in this case, you will probably be given a formula which expresses acceleration).

Comment: Thankyou. Would the differentiation/integration equations also work for things that have a linear acceleration graph too?

Comment: @gogobebe2 "differentiation/integration" **always** works.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Oh ok. So it's just easier to use the kinematic equations when possible?

Comment: @gogobebe2 yep.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Cool, thanks for your help!